# How to copy file from Server to Mac through python?

Tags: python, macos, server, copy

i want to copy file from the following path to my local machine mac but i am un able to do so it gives error that this is not a directory 
 \builds\prgbuilds-readonly\MacIOS\DgnClientSdk
i am using the following script in mac

> import ftplib from urlparse import urlparse import ftputil import sys
>   import os import socket import shutil import pickle import subprocess
>
> return_list = []
>
> ```
> def VerifySharedPath(path):    
> if not os.path.exists(path):        
>     print path,"does not exists"
>     sys.exit(1)
> ```
>
> def
>   Download_From_Shared_Path(srcPath,destPath,buildNo,FileName,subPath,language_prefix):
>       VerifySharedPath(srcPath)
>       dirList = os.listdir(srcPath)
>       Lasttested_build_no=''
>       #find latest build directory using highest number in the directory list
>       LATEST = buildNo
>       if language_prefix == None:
>           language_prefix = ''
>       for dir in dirList:
>          if buildNo in dir and language_prefix in dir:
>               if LATEST < dir:
>                   LATEST = dir
>       print '***LATEST build is '+ LATEST
>
> ```
> SRC_PATH = os.path.join(srcPath,LATEST)
>
> VerifySharedPath(SRC_PATH)    
>
> DEST_PATH = os.path.join(destPath,LATEST)
>
> if subPath != None: #subpath is given, join it with source path and verify 
>     SRC_PATH = os.path.join(SRC_PATH,subPath)        
>     VerifySharedPath(SRC_PATH)
> print 'LATEST build will be downloaded from ',SRC_PATH
> #print os.listdir(SRC_PATH)
> if not os.path.exists(DEST_PATH):   #latest is build is not downloaded yet
>     if FileName == '':     #check whether source path is a file or directory then copy it through respective functions.
>         try:
>             shutil.copytree(SRC_PATH,DEST_PATH)               
>         except shutil.Error as e:
>              print('Error: %s' % e)
>              return_list.insert(0,"Fail")
>              return_list.insert(1,LATEST)
>              return return_list
>         except IOError as e:
>               print('Error: %s' % e.strerror)
>               return_list.insert(0,"Fail")
>               return_list.insert(1,LATEST)
>               return return_list
>     else:            
>        try:         
>            if SRC_PATH.endswith(FileName):
>               DEST_PATH=DEST_PATH.strip(FileName)
>               os.mkdir(DEST_PATH)
>               shutil.copy(SRC_PATH,DEST_PATH)
>            else:
>             os.mkdir(DEST_PATH) 
>             files = os.listdir(SRC_PATH)  
>             files =[i for i in files if FileName in i]
>             print files
>             if len(files) >0 :
>                 #FileName = FileName.strip('*')
>                 for file in files:
>                     FileName = file
>                     FILE_PATH = os.path.join(DEST_PATH,FileName)
>                     SRC_PATH_tem = os.path.join(SRC_PATH,FileName)     
>                     print '*** Downloading "%s" Started: Please wait....'%FileName           
>                     shutil.copy2(SRC_PATH_tem,FILE_PATH)        
>             else:
>              return_list.insert(0,"Fail")
>              return_list.insert(1,LATEST)
>              return return_list
>        except shutil.Error as e:
>             print('Error: %s' % e)
>             return_list.insert(0,"Fail")
>             return_list.insert(1,LATEST)
>             return return_list
>        except IOError as e:
>             print('Error: %s' % e.strerror)
>             return_list.insert(0,"Fail")
>             return_list.insert(1,LATEST)
>             return return_list
>     print '*** Latest build is avaialable at %s ' % DEST_PATH
>     print '*** Build is there. Happy Testing!'
>     return_list.insert(0, "Pass")
>     return_list.insert(1, DEST_PATH)
>     return return_list
> else:
>     print "LATEST BUILD IS ALREADY DOWNLOADED"
>     return_list.insert(0,"LATEST BUILD IS ALREADY DOWNLOADED")
>     return_list.insert(1,LATEST)
>     return return_list
> ```

Comment: Are you trying to copy a file from a remote machine (I'm guessing Windows because of the ` \ ` path separator) to your local OS X machine? Have you tried ftplib in the standard library? https://docs.python.org/2/library/ftplib.html

Comment: yes i am copying from the remote windows machine to my local OS X i used the same script for my windows machine it works there fine but in MAC it gives error

Comment: it says that the path doesn't exist \builds\prgbuilds-readonly\MacIOS\DgnClientSdk